# How does posts.so post directly to the instagram API

Tags: instagram

https://posts.so/ seems to allow users to post directly to instagram from the web without going to  the instagram api first. How do they do this? I don't see that documented anywhere in the Instagram API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official Instagram API does not allow uploading photos, since they want to encourage "life on the go" usage of the app.

Since [posts.so](https://postso.com/) are certainly not using the official API to upload photos, there are 2 ways they could do it:

- They made a partnership with Instagram, which gave them access to some special Instagram API for partners. This option is [highly unlikely](http://help.instagram.com/447700568611091), though.
- They used the unofficial API. This is the API that the Instagram's iOS/Android apps use to upload photos. It can be easily reverse-engineered by using a decompiler or a packet analyzer such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

The unofficial API has been documented [here](https://github.com/mislav/instagram/wiki). The specific method that you're looking for is [post new media](https://github.com/mislav/instagram/wiki/media#wiki-post-new-media). Check this code for example:

https://code.google.com/p/twitubas/source/browse/common/instagram.php